# lightweight (quasi-random) integer fingerprint of C string

Tags: c, cryptography

I would like to generate a nicely-mixed-up integer fingerprint of an arbitrary C string (s).  Most C strings will consist of ASCII text characters:

- I want very different fingerprints for similar strings, esp such similar strings as "ab" and "ba"
- I want it to be difficult to invert back from the fingerprint to the string (well, my string is typically longer than 32 bits, which means that many strings would map into the same integer), which means again that I want similar strings to yield very different codes;
- I want to use the 32 bits available to me efficiently in the integer result,
- I want the function source to be small
- I want the function to be fast.

one usage is security (but not encryption) related.  I can ask a user for a text password, convert it into an integer for storage and later test whether this integer is correct.  (I know I could store strings, but I don't want to.  guessing a 32-bit integer correctly is impossible if my program can slow down incorrect attempts to the point where brute force cannot work faster than password guessing.  another use of this function is as the start of a hash index function (mod array length) into an array.)

alas, I am probably reinventing the wheel here.  such functions have probably been written a million times, and by people who are much more versed in cryptography.  I don't need AES, of course, but something much more lightweight.  the use is different.

my first thinking was

- mod 64 each character to take advantage of the ASCII text aspect.  now I have 6 bits.  call this x.
- I can place a 6bit string into 5 locations in a 32-bit space, leaving 2 bits over.
- take the current string index position (0, 1, 2...), mod5 it to determine where I want to start to place my x into my running integer result code.  XOR my x into this running-result integer.
- use the remaining 2 bits to increment a counter [mod 4 to prevent overflow] for each character processed.

then I thought that bit operations may be computer-fast but take more source code.  I can think of other choices.  take each index position i and multiply it by an ascii representation of each character [or the x from above], and call this y[i].  now do the following:

- calculate the natural logarithm of the sums of the y (or this sum plus the running result), and just pretend that the first 32 bits of this result [maybe leaving off the first few bits], which are really a double, are an integer representation.  I can XOR each bitint(log(y[i])) into the running integer result.
- do it even cheaper.  just add the y's, and then do the logarithm with 32-bit pickoff just once at the end.  alternatively, run a sum-y through srand as a seed and grab a rand.

there are probably a few other ways to do it, too.  in sum, the function should map strings into very different integers, be short to code, and be very fast.

Any pointers?

Comment: You haven't supplied remotely enough evidence that you can't just use an established cryptographic hash function. There is no reason to suspect it'll be a bottleneck, and using an existing implementation shouldn't be much code.

Comment: You don't need AES because AES is a cipher, but you do need a cryptographic hash function, according to your description. Anything that is a solution to your problem is a cryptographic hash function. The use is not “different”: this is exactly what cryptographic hash functions are used for (among other applications). You had better learn about salts, too.

Comment: See “Password verification” in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Applications

Comment: pascal's link leads to PBKDF2, scrypt, and https://password-hashing.net/ , which are similar...except that low resource demands are considered bad there.

Comment: If you're using this for anything other than a hash table please just use a crypto library. Do not do password hashes with your own code.

Comment: also, I wondered about the following: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11839/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hash-function-and-a-cryptographic-hash-function .    I think non-cryptographic functions are "deadly" when someone can see the hashed values (numbers), because they can then easily find a string to match it.  they are "ok" if the hash values themselves are hidden, and one merely wants to "shorten" the password string-equality tests.  CRCs seem very efficient at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common method of generating a non-reversible digest or hash of a string is to generate a Cyclic Redundancy Checksum (CRC).

Source for CRC is widely available, in this case you should use a common CRC-32 such as that used by Ethernet.  Different CRCs work on the same principle, buy use different polynomials. Do not be tempted to invent your own polynomial; the distribution is likely to be sub-optimal.

Comment: However, CRC is far from difficult to reverse. It's designed to catch unintentional changes, nothing more.

Comment: @delnan : How would you propose to reverse it?  i.e. reproduce the original string from the CRC alone?  It cannot be done because information is necessarily discarded. Detecting errors is the original intent of CRC but it also makes a good hashing function.  It can be used also to store a "digest" of a string such as a password, so that the secured system does not store or have any knowledge of the original password (encrypted or plain text), it simply CRCs the entered string and compares that to the stored CRC.

Comment: "Reverse" in the sense of finding a string that produces the same CRC, since (as you point out) neither CRCs nor hash functions are injective. But because it's easy to produce a collision, it does not make for a good cryptographic hash function, for example it's *not* suited for authentication.

Comment: @denlan : Reading the link in Pascal Cuoq's comment, I do see your point about CRC-32 being "weak" cryptographically.  I think however as you commented previously a one-way-hash of some form is the solution.  I would say that your comment was in fact an answer and should have perhaps been posted as such - I'd vote for it.

Comment: injective is not important in my case, simply because we are mapping a longer bit-string into a shorter integer.  there will be an infinite number of strings that map into the same code.  so, CRCs are indeed working well for exactly my purpose, and crc32 is a standard!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a "hash". Two examples of hash functions I'm aware of that return short integers are MurmurHash and SipHash. MurmurHash, as I recall, is not designed to be a cryptographic hash, while SipHash, on the other hand, is indeed designed with security in mind, as stated on its [homepage](https://131002.net/siphash/). MurmurHash has 2 versions that return a 32-bit and a 64-bit output. SipHash returns a 64-bit output.